# Align matrix to be flush left with delimiter in 'align'

Tags: align, amsmath, matrices

I'm using amsmath and matrices in the align environment and can't get the text at the end of a line to be flush left.I would like the matrices on the right to be flush with the matrices on the left and not the right margins. [image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mbox{rref}(A|\vec{b}) \quad &= \quad 
\begin{bmatrix}
2  &  2  &  0  &  0  &  2 & -2 \\
13 &  13 &  -3 &  -6 &  4 & 2 \\
-9 &  -9 &  1  &  2  &  -6& 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \rightarrow \quad    
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  1 & -1 \\
13 &  13 &  -3 &  -6 &  4 & 2 \\
-9 &  -9 &  1  &  2  &  -6& 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\quad &\rightarrow \quad  
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  1 & -1 \\
0  &  0  &  -3 &  -6 &  -9& -11  \\
-9 &  -9 &  1  &  2  &  -6& 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\quad \rightarrow \quad   
\begin{bmatrix}
1  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  1 & -1 \\
0  &  0  &  -3 &  -6 &  -9& -11  \\
0  &  0  &  1  &  2  &  3& -5 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you write "flush with the arrows", do you get the effect you want by deleting the `&` after the `\rightarrow`? You could add a `\quad` space to keep symmetry. Also, it is good form to include a complete ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Updated the code per requirements and changed delimiters from your suggestion. The effect minimizes the results in the sample code but does not solve the issue.

Comment: Still too many `&`s.  Delete the `&` after the `=` in the first row after `\begin{flalign*}`. Then delete both `&`s in the first line with `\rightarrow`. Then delete the `&` after the `\rightarrow` before the 3rd matrix, and delete both `&`s around the `\rightarrow` before the 4th matrix. Lastly, don't leave math mode so much. Your code `$R_1$ $\div$ $2$ $\rightarrow$ $R_1$` should be `$R_1\div 2 \rightarrow R_1$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
\documentclass[oneside,letterpaper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{
\edef\arraystretch{1.25}%
\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\mbox{rref}(A|\vec{b}) \quad &=&  
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
2  &  2  &  0  &  0  &  2 & -2 \\
13 &  13 &  -3 &  -6 &  4 & 2 \\
-9 &  -9 &  1  &  2  &  -6& 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
 &&\rightarrow& \quad    
\stackrel{\mbox{$R_1 \div 2 \rightarrow R_1$}}{
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
1  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  1 & -1 \\
13 &  13 &  -3 &  -6 &  4 & 2 \\
-9 &  -9 &  1  &  2  &  -6& 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}} &\\[1.5em]
\quad &\rightarrow&  
\stackrel{\mbox{$R_2 - 13R_1\rightarrow R_2$}}{
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
1  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  1 & -1 \\
0  &  0  &  -3 &  -6 &  -9& -11  \\
-9 &  -9 &  1  &  2  &  -6& 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}} 
 &&\rightarrow& \quad   
\stackrel{\mbox{$R_3 + 9R_1\rightarrow R_2$}}{
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
1  &  1  &  0  &  0  &  1 & -1 \\
0  &  0  &  -3 &  -6 &  -9& -11  \\
0  &  0  &  1  &  2  &  3& -5 \\
\end{bmatrix}} &\\[1.5em] 
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SandyG Thanks.  hadn't even noticed those before.